# BroadCasting Location so another device can see its current location

Tags: android, google-maps, location, broadcast

I'm trying to make an android app for transportation, i need to broadcast the current location of the transport so the passengers can see where it is, is there a way to do it with android? do i need an external library?
my app works with google maps and connects with a Django server using retrofit.

Comment: "i need to broadcast the current location of the transport" -- please edit your question and explain, in detail, where and how you are getting the current location of the transport.

Comment: well if i knew how i wouldn't be asking this question, where? in another android device using google maps. thanks!

Comment: "in another android device using google maps" -- are you trying to say that you have an Android device on the "transport" that is collecting the location of the "transport"?

Comment: yep, one device is on the transport getting the location, and theres another device somewhere else getting the current location of the transport :D

Answer (score 1):

Step #1: Have your tracking device ("one device is on the transport getting the location") send the location data to the Django server.

Step #2: Implement [Google Cloud Messaging](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/) or some other push system with your end-user Android app and server.

Step #3: Have the Django server push a message to the end-user Android app when the location changes for a transport that they user has registered interest in.